# can we assign the workflow to particular user,instead of all users

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

here how can we do the below steps:

when the customer upload the document , he can abble to choose the approver with drop down box, instead of assigning to all approvers in the workflow group or list of approvers.

can any one please suggest me to do this

Thanks advance...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need enable the sharepoint 2010 workflows feature of site collection(if you using SharePoint Online).

You should assign the "approval workflow sharepoint 2010" to a library. In library, set the option "Require content approval for submitted items?" to yes.

See the links:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfGDBzQvAwI

Comment: i have alredy configured with all above, i need to assign the workflow task to particuler user in the dropdown option, can we create like this

Comment: You can edit the model of this workflow in SPD. You can edit the forms with infopath.